# How does travis-ci reply back to github that tests are passed?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I am trying to understand how travis-ci works, first I authorize the app to create webhooks for pull requests, push, etc,.. then travis gets a notification whenever there is a pull request. but how does it reply back to github that the tests are passed?

Comment: [The official GH guide](https://developer.github.com/guides/building-a-ci-server) probably contains all the data you will need.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь thanks a lot, you should have wrote the answer, so that I can accept it and others will be pointed at the right information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the official [GitHub's guide on building CI servers](https://developer.github.com/guides/building-a-ci-server) tells us in the [Working with statuses](https://developer.github.com/guides/building-a-ci-server/#working-with-statuses) section, one changes the build status by calling the `create_status` function on the client handle obtained via the [Octocat.rb](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) gem like so:

```
def process_pull_request(pull_request)
  @client.create_status(pull_request['base']['repo']['full_name'], pull_request['head']['sha'], 'pending')
  sleep 2 # do busy work...
  @client.create_status(pull_request['base']['repo']['full_name'], pull_request['head']['sha'], 'success')
  puts "Pull request processed!"
end
```

Where `process_pull_request()` is a function receiving the JSON payload `PUSH`ed by GitHub itself.

There's an [API documentation section](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status) devoted strictly to status creation directly via the API.

Answer (score -3):

eightnoteight,

Travis replies back to GitHub saying that tests are passed through webhooks similar to the ones that create a notification when a pull request or push are made.For Travis CI to know what to build, you have to add a .travis.yml file to your repository.The file will contain the language you are using, the gem versions and or dependencies you have . Travis CI tests your project against the versions of the language you are using and after each commit or push you trigger a Travis CI build, that results in a passing or failing test.

** I've gathered most of this reply from [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/)